# Cant require object export by index in same folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the example app: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-bash-g7gg2

The scenarios:

- I CAN call func1 and func2 in exec.js
- I CAN call `func2()` inside `func1()` importing in this way: `const func2 = require('./func2')`
- I CANT call `func2` inside `func1()` importing in this way: `const { func2 } = require('./')`

Why the same functions import works in exec.js and dont works in /src/func1.js ?
I receive "func2 is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

in the last scenario, you are requiring no file at all. It's like getting a function out of tin air.

Also, the syntax `const  { func2 }` is importing an exported property of an object to a variable through [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). In your case, you are exporting an anonymous function. There is no property `func2` to import.

if you wish to import `func2` using the `const { func2 } = require('./func2')`, you need to export that from `func2`:

```
module.exports = {
    func2: () => {
        console.log("func2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Those two examples are definitely not the same.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek You were right, i've edited my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: Also, please take a closer look at what OP has a problem with. In fact, he can't import `{ func2 }` from the `./` and not from `./func2`.

Comment: @Nicolas I understand your approach, but I still wonder why I can use object destructuring with an anonymous function in the `exec.js` file, line 1?

Comment: @Renan that is a good question. I guess I don't really understand Js module either.

Comment: @Renan from what i understand from [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), the require function is loading the file `index.js` if present. And since your are exporting both function as property in this file, they might be available to import from other files. But i'm not sure about what i'm advancing.